# asp.net mvc index action is called automatically after ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that creates a record in the database:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description")] SampleViewModel sampleVM)
    {
        try
        {
            _service.Add(sampleVM);
            this.ShowMessage(new ToastMessage(ToastType.Success, "Record Added", ToastrDisplayType.TopLeft));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ShowMessage(new ToastMessage(ToastType.Error, ex.Message, ToastrDisplayType.TopLeft));
            return Json("failed");
        }

        return Json("success");
    }
```

this Action is called by AJAX:

```
 $().ready(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var serviceURL = '';

            var sample = {
                "Id": $('#hdnId').val(),
                "Name": $("#txtName").val(),
                "Description": $("#txtDescription").val(),
            };

            if (save_method == 'add') {
                serviceURL = '@Url.Action("Create", "Samples")';
            }
            else if (save_method == 'edit') {
                serviceURL = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Samples")';
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: addRequestVerificationToken(sample),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    handleAjaxMessages();
                },

            });
        });
    });
```

The problem is that the Index Action is called automatically after the Create Action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

[Fiddler snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVXgo.png)

The Toast message is not displayed because the Index Action is called, How can I call the Create Action only (without calling the Index Action)?

Comment: whatever you have posted seems fine. Can you see that if create action is being called at all or not?

Comment: Yes it is called, I have put a break point.

Comment: then your toast message should also be called. After which line of code, does the control actually passes to the index method

Comment: show the HTML for btnSave please

Comment: I used this for toast messages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474035/displaying-errors-and-exceptions-in-toastr-or-similar-method-using-mvc4-and-en  . the html for save button is <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@Resources.Captions.Save</button>  .  when i hit save the Index action is called then the create action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `"#btnSave"` is a `<button type="submit" />` button. The browser will do the following in order:

1. Invoke your own click handler, that you have shown in your code.
2. Post the `<form>` that your button is in to the server and reload the page with the answer that it gives.

You have two options: either you remove the form and have a regular `<button>` (without `type="submit"`), or you modify your click handler a little:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // notice this line
        var serviceURL = '';
```